# table-cell doesn't break word on IE9

Tags: html, css

take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Y7NAR/2/.

`display: table-cell; max-width:100px; word-wrap:break-word;` works fine in chrome but the words don't break in IE9.

any solution?

Comment: First, its now `overflow-wrap` ... second, try this out => http://www.last-child.com/word-wrapping-for-internet-explorer/

Comment: Just a side note, it works in my IE10.

Comment: @Kyle i would imagine so. IE9 is not a real browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following in your CSS:

```
#cntnr .section {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #fcc;
    text-align: center;
    max-width:100px;
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx\

Fiddle Update: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/BwaMt/

Comment: thanks. it seems like the trick is to use `word-break: break-all`

Comment: Glad to help.   I tend to reread the specs on word-break and word-wrap whenever I use them since the syntax of the two are similar.  You only need the browser specific properties (-ms-...) if you are targeting older IE browsers.  All the best!

Comment: break-all and break-word are different stuff.
and unfortunately -ms-word-break: break-all; will be applied to newer IE browsers as well. I'm sure about IE10 but haven't tested it in IE11